# Problem with SDO_GEOMETRY C# and Oracle 12

Tags: c#, oracle, visual-studio, iis, user-defined-types

Hello I have a c# application that access an oracle database(version 12.1.0).
I have a table that contains SDO_GEOMETRY COLUMN. I have generated a udt file of sdo_geomtry with oracle developer tools for visual studio.
Everything worked fine with oracle 11 but when I have upgraded to 12c I noticed a weird problem, after selecting large number of rows(20,000), the SDO_ORDINATES field will be null(all other columns are ok). I thought that the data was corrupted but when I checked with the database the data was ok. I even found the first entity that had SDO_ORDINATES as NULL and selected it with my application, everything was ok, SDO_ORDINATES had the proper values.
I am working with Oracle Data.Access.dll version 4.121.2.0.

Things I tried to do:

- I tried to create a new UDT from this thread: [How to declare MDSYS.Sdo_Geometry in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29160849/how-to-declare-mdsys-sdo-geometry-in-c-sharp), same problem occurs.
- Tried to export the data again to older database(with version 11): it worked.
- Tried to use sdo_util.to_wktgeometry and it worked, but I dont want to use it because it has a big impact on performance.

I am starting to think that it is a memory problem but dont know for sure...

Any ideas?

```
SELECT id, geometry FROM locations; 

example of geometry: 
mdsys.sdo_geometry(2003, 4326, mdsys.sdo_point) type (null,null,null),
   {1, 1003, 1},
   {1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.1, 1.5, 1.1, 1.0, 1.3, 2, 1.7})
```

Comment: Can we see your query?  Also,include a few rows of sample data from the table.

Comment: SELECT id, geometry FROM locations; example of geometry: mdsys.sdo_geometry(2003, 4326, mdsys.sdo_point)type(null,null,null),{1, 1003, 1},{1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.1, 1.5, 1.1, 1.0, .1.3, 2, 1.7}) @belwood